# submit buttons are not getting highlighted when navigating through tab key

Tags: java, html, jsp

When I navigate through tab key in my web page submit button and some other components are not getting highlighted while some are getting highlighted like this JPG.

[image: Link with lighlight]

In myJsp if cursor is in any text field when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key  it should submit but it is not getting submitted.  I go to the submit button through <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

What could be the reason?  Any pointer to tutorial for these kind of issue?

### myJsp.jsp

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="_eventId_search" value="Search"/>
<button class="save_button_common"     onClick="submitForm('save')">Save</button>
<button class="reset_button_common" onClick="submitForm('reset')">Reset>   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="save_button_common"     onClick="submitForm('save')">Save</button>
<button class="reset_button_common" onClick="submitForm('reset')">Reset>   </button>
```

No!

- There is no such thing as a `button` element. It is an `input` with a `type` of `button`.
- `Reset>` should be `Reset`
- There is some odd spacing

Try..

```
<input type='button' class="save_button_common" onClick="submitForm('save')" value="Save">
<input type='button' class="reset_button_common" onClick="submitForm('reset')" value="Reset">
```

But don't take my word for it, ask the experts.  Always validate the output using the [W3C mark-up validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).

---

Note that the above HTML will produce a button that looks something like..

<kbd>Save</kbd>

..rather than..

[image]

..which looks more like a link.  Those inputs above might be converted to something that looks like (or rather is) a link.  But that would not be the 'path of least surprise' for the end user.  They expect a form submit/reset button to look like a ..button (funny that).

Comment: thanks Andrew Thompson for your response. actually other components are getting highlighted like Help link and checkboxes but submit buttons are not getting highlighted. Thanks.

Comment: thanks,Andrew, input type='button' works in my case. thanks a lot

Comment: I know it's been a while, but for the record `button` is a valid HTML element now.